# Parse, Fetch and Display Current User

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I'm attempting to fetch the currentuser's username, and have it displayed on screen, here is my code:

```
Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
  success: function(user) {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current(); 
    currentUser.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser) {
      var name = fetchedUser.getUsername();
    });
    $('.alertmsg').html('<div id="alert"><p>You are' + name + '</div>');
  }
});
```

Everything is working fine, but the username won't display.

Hope that this is an easy fix!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should move the line at which you update the html of `alertmsg` in the callback, that is because `name` is scoped to the callback function and does not exist outside of it:

```
Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
  success: function(user) {
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current(); 
    currentUser.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser) {
      var name = fetchedUser.getUsername();
      $('.alertmsg').html('<div id="alert"><p>You are' + name + '</div>');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @Overflow please mark the answer as a solution if it worked for you.

Comment: @Chad sorry about that, I was waiting to do it. Thanks again :)

Comment: No problem @Overflow, Stackoverflow doesn't let you until a certain timeout passed, thanks!