# Parse, Fetch and Display ObjectID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

Thanks to this previous thread: [Parse, Fetch and Display Current User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612968/parse-fetch-and-display-current-user)

I managed to display the Current User's username, 
I figured that I could also display the user's ID using `.getObjectId();`

So I gave that a try, but I get an error in the console telling me that it is *undefined*.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

          Parse.initialize("xxxx", "xxxx");

         var currentUser = Parse.User.current(); 
         currentUser.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser){
                var name = fetchedUser.getUsername();
                var uniqueID = fetchedUser.getObjectId();
            $('.container').append('<ul class="nav pull-right"><li><a id="nametag" href="#">' + name + '</a></li></ul>');
            $('.btn-box-row row-fluid').append('<a href="#" class="btn-box big span4"><i class=" icon-random"></i><b>' + uniqueID + '</b>');
            });
         });
```

Comment: have you tried to use simply fetchedUser.id ?

Comment: @LucaIaco post your answer as an answer so others finding this question can benefit... answers hidden in comments aren't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with fetchedUser.id

Hope it helps